# Magento2 - How to maintain custom log the order status changes?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, order-status

In Magento2.3, I want to maintain the custom log table when order status change.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `sales_order_save_after` event and observer the status and log your data in a custom table

Answer (score 0):

I think there is already a table **sales_order_status_history** and you can access through vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Status/**HistoryRepository**

It does not log status change unless a comment is attached with it.

At least it will save your time in creating custom table and its files.